How do I set the directory for the .fileImporter view modifier in SwiftUI on macOS
I'm trying to direct the .fileImporter to start in a particular directory (the app has User Selected File read/write file access), have created simple playground exhibiting the behavior:
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct FileOpenExample : View {

  @State private var fileDialogPresented: Bool = false
  private var initialDirectory: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myuser/Library/Application%20Support/com.mydomain.myapp")
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      fileDialogPresented = true
    } label: {
      Text("Select File")
    }
    .fileDialogDefaultDirectory(initialDirectory)
    .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileDialogPresented, allowedContentTypes: [.utf8PlainText]) { result in
    }
  }
}

let sampleView = FileOpenExample()

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(sampleView)

It behaves similarly in the playground or in my app, basically opening to the running location of the app, not the URL I'm specifying (the directory at the URL I specify does exist)
I've tried putting the .fileDialogDefaultDirectory above and below the .fileImporter to no avail.  The Apple documentation is correct/complete but doesn't give much guidance or an example of how to use it correctly.  Advice?

try moving .fileDialogDefaultDirectory after .fileImporter, such as in this example code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FileOpenExample()
        .padding()
    }
}

struct FileOpenExample: View {
    @State private var fileDialogPresented: Bool = false
    let initialDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/yourusername/somedir")
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            fileDialogPresented = true
        } label: {
            Text("Select File")
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileDialogPresented, allowedContentTypes: [.item]) { result in
            print("\n---> result: \(result)\n")
        }
        .fileDialogDefaultDirectory(initialDirectory) // <--- here
    }
}

Tested using Xcode 16.1 beta on macOS Sequoia 15.1

Thanks.  As I mentioned I do the same, but don't get the result I expect.  I think it's related to AppState of where the last directory where the File Open dialog was opened is presented.  So if I navigate to the directory then reopen the dialog it goes to that same directory.  Currently investigating how to override the previous directory setting.

...if I navigate to the directory then reopen the dialog it goes to that same directory.
This is not what I get when I put .fileDialogDefaultDirectory(initialDirectory) after
.fileImporter.
I only get that behaviour if I have
.fileDialogDefaultDirectory(initialDirectory) before
.fileImporter, using Xcode 16.1 beta on tested on macOS Sequoia 15.1.
